# How to resize image from library of UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How to resize image from UIImagePickerController if the length, width, or both of the photos exceed 1500, both the length and width must be reduced to 65%. For example if the size of the photo is 2000x3000 after resizing both parameters should be multiplied by 0.65 and become 1300x1950.
And, if the length and width of the photo does not exceed 1500, the photo should remain unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code to resize based on max size and scale.

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeImage(maxSize: CGFloat, scale : CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let size = self.size
        
        if (size.width > maxSize || size.height > maxSize) {
            let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale)
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
            
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
            self.draw(in: rect)
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            
            return newImage!
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

let resizedImage = yourImage.resizeImage(maxSize: 1500, scale: 0.65)